# Window is hidden even though QCloseEvent is ignored

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I’m currently trying to port my Qt application to Mac OSX and just came across the following problem:

One of my window classes (derived from QMainWindow) displays a dialog box when the close button is pressed, where you can save/discard changes or abort. This is done by reimplementing closeEvent as follows:

```
void ResultsWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
{
    if (isWindowModified())
    {
        activateWindow();
        QMessageBox::StandardButton button = QMessageBox::warning(
                this,
                APPLICATION_NAME,
                "Warning: data have been modified. Do you want to save the "
                    "changes?",
                QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Abort,
                QMessageBox::Abort);
        switch (button)
        {
            case QMessageBox::Save:
                if (!Save())
                {
                    event->ignore();
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case QMessageBox::Discard:
                break;
            case QMessageBox::Abort:
            default:
                event->ignore();
                return;
        }
    }
    event->accept();
}
```

The expected behavior is as follows: If you click “Abort”, the event is ignored and the window stays open. This works as expected on Linux and Windows. On OSX, however, the window is hidden, but still active in the background. What am I missing here? How can I make sure the window stays open?

**Update:**
I somehow think that this is a problem with Qt5. If the `closeEvent` method consists of nothing but `event->ignore();` the window is still closed. I don’t think this is the intended behavior. Maybe I should post this problem to the Qt mailing list…

**Update:
This was a bug in Qt and is solved since version 5.1.**

Comment: If you have time, just try this to see if I can answer this: call ` event->accept();` as a first function (disable closing the application completely), and see if window will remain visible despite clicking on close button.

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand you correctly: I just replaced the function body with `event->accept();` and also with `event->ignore();`. In both cases the window was closed, but in the latter case, it remained active in the background.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does doing QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(show()) have any kind of effect?

Comment: Which version of Qt? I'm using 4.8.1 on Mac OX 10.8.2 and it works fine.

Comment: I’m using Qt 5.0.0 on Snow Leopard. The same affect also occurs on a recent Mountain Lion.

Comment: @Chris: putting `QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(show()));` or even `QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(show()));` at the end of the function doesn’t reopen the window. Strange...

Comment: Calling `show()` from outside also has no effect. `isHidden()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Same here with Qt 5.0.0 or Qt 5.0.1.
However if you set WindowModality as ApplicationModal or WindowModal it works. Press Cmd+Q to quit and to obtain the message box.

[image: windowModality in Qt Creator]

I presume the problem is originated by the differences between Mac OS X UI and other UI. Perhaps some additional work on Qt will enable them to resolve the problem.

Even if you reimplement QMainWindow::event() you obtain the same result.

Comment: In facts, if you have WindowModality = NonModal and use cmd+Q, when you press "Abort" the windows doesn't disappear. If you use the red button and then "Abort" the window disappears, but you can press cmd+Q to have message box again.

Comment: Hmm, this somehow works, but not really… I set the window modality to `Qt::WindowModal` but now its close button is disabled and also the main window is no longer accessible, as if the results window was application modal. But if I close the application from the task bar, the dialog appears and choosing ‘Abort’ leads to the window staying open…

Comment: In facts, the red button shouldn't close the app, but only the window; it's different from the task bar (cmd+Q). I mean, I hope this could be a workaround (especially if this is the main window of your application), until Qt developers resolve the bug.

Comment: The problem is, that the red button is not available with your suggestion. This is not the main window of my application, and there is no way to close it now if I don’t want to add other buttons. And furthermore, I can no longer access the main window because the window modality also is wrong somehow… For now I would rather leave it as it was before :-/

Comment: A not main window which is a subclass of QMainWindow? Strange. Why not a QDialog?

Comment: It is roughly like this: I have a main window where I can configure my calculations and hit a button to start them. Then another window opens (the ResultsWindow this problem is all about), which is something like a secondary main window which allows me to do a lot of things to explore the data and which also opens its own dialogs and so on. Multiple results windows can be open in the same time.

Comment: Until the bug is resolved, when user press Abort you could save the data, close the window and then reopen another (in the same position) reloading data.

Comment: Yes, this might do it as a workaround, even though I don’t like it. I could just pass over the data internally, no need to save and load…

Answer (score 1):

I have Qt 4.7 on Mac 10.7 and I can't reproduce this error.

I believe simply putting `show()` between the `Q_OS_MAC` macro every time you ignore the `event` should do the trick. Something like this:

```
event->ignore();
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
     show();
#endif
```

This may not be the perfect solution, but certainly a fix for this problem.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. The window still closes. But I expected this, as calling show() from outside, after the window is being hidden, also has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
case QMessageBox::Abort:
                default:
                        event->ignore();
                        return;
```

try doing

```
case QMessageBox::Abort:
                       event->ignore();
                       return;
 default:
         break
```

Comment: This doesn’t change anything, the problem is not a malformed switch structure.

Answer (score 0):

As I get this bug too, I created a bug report here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30899

Answer (score 0):

Ugly workaround (tested and working), add this just after event->ignore():

```
QTimer::singleShot(0,this,SLOT(hide()));
QTimer::singleShot(100,this,SLOT(show()));
```